# Javascript Travel Calculator not working

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm trying to make a JavaScript calculator that will calculate the cost for 4 families to travel by train. The cost for one adult ticket is $32 and the cost for a child is $20 with a $10 commission fee. This is my JavaScript. When i run it in Firefox debugger it says amountdue1 is not defined?

```
<script language="JavaScript/text">
var child = 20;
var adult = 32;

function amountdue1() {
{
if (document.calc.familyname1.value === null || document.calc.familyname1.value.length === 0) 
{
alert("Please enter your family name");
}
else
{


var numadults = document.calc.num_Adults1.selectedIndex;
var numchildren = document.calc.num_Children1.selectedIndex;

document.calc.totaldue.value = (numadults * adult) + (numchildren * child) + 10; 

}};
```

this table is in the body. There would be 4 amountdue(s) but i couldn't get one to work.

```
<table width=100% border=1 class="one" id="table_one">
<br>
<tr>
<th width=20%>Family One</th>
<th width=20%>Family Two</th>
<th width=20%>Family Three</th>
<th width=20%>Family Four</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align=center>
<br>
<input type="text" name="familyname1" maxlength="20"><br>
</td>
<td align=center>
<br>
<input type="text" name="familyname2" maxlength="20"><br>
</td>
<td align=center>
<br>
<input type="text" name="familyname3" maxlength="20">
</td>
<td align=center>
<br>
<input type="text" name="familyname4" maxlength="20"><br>
</tr>
<tr>            
<td align=center><br>
<select id="num_Adults1" onchange="return total1()">
<option value=0 selected>0 Adults</option>
<option value=1>1 Adult</option>
<option value=1>2 Adults</option>
<option value=1>3 Adults</option>
<option value=1>4 Adults</option>
<option value=1>5 Adults</option>
<option value=1>6 Adults</option>
<option value=1>7 Adults</option>
<option value=1>8 Adults</option>
</select>

</td>
<td align=center><br>
<select id="num_Adults2" onchange="return total2()">
<option value=0 selected>0 Adults</option>
<option value=1>1 Adult</option>
<option value=1>2 Adults</option>
<option value=1>3 Adults</option>
<option value=1>4 Adults</option>
<option value=1>5 Adults</option>
<option value=1>6 Adults</option>
<option value=1>7 Adults</option>
 <option value=1>8 Adults</option>
</select>
</td>
<td align=center><br>
<select id="num_Adults3" onchange="return total3()">
<option value=0 selected>0 Adults</option>
<option value=1>1 Adult</option>
<option value=1>2 Adults</option>
<option value=1>3 Adults</option>
<option value=1>4 Adults</option>
<option value=1>5 Adults</option>
<option value=1>6 Adults</option>
<option value=1>7 Adults</option>
<option value=1>8 Adults</option>
</select>
</td>
<td align=center><br>
<select id="num_Adults4" onchange="return total4()">
<option value=0 selected>0 Adults</option>
<option value=1>1 Adult</option>
<option value=1>2 Adults</option>
<option value=1>3 Adults</option>
<option value=1>4 Adults</option>
<option value=1>5 Adults</option>
<option value=1>6 Adults</option>
<option value=1>7 Adults</option>
<option value=1>8 Adults</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align=center><br>
<select id="num_Children1" onchange="return total1()">
<option value=0 selected>0 Children</option>
<option value=1>1 Child</option>
<option value=1>2 Children</option>
<option value=1>3 Children</option>
<option value=1>4 Children</option>
<option value=1>5 Children</option>
<option value=1>6 Children</option>
<option value=1>7 Children</option>
<option value=1>8 Children</option>
</select>
</td>               
<td align=center>
<br>
<select id="num_Children2" onchange="return total2()">
<option value=0 selected>0 Children</option>
<option value=1>1 Child</option>
<option value=1>2 Children</option>
<option value=1>3 Children</option>
<option value=1>4 Children</option>
<option value=1>5 Children</option>
<option value=1>6 Children</option>
<option value=1>7 Children</option>
<option value=1>8 Children</option>
</select>
</td>
<td align=center><br>
<select id="num_Children3" onchange="return total3()">
<option value=0 selected>0 Children</option>
<option value=1>1 Child</option>
<option value=1>2 Children</option>
<option value=1>3 Children</option>
<option value=1>4 Children</option>
<option value=1>5 Children</option>
<option value=1>6 Children</option>
<option value=1>7 Children</option>
<option value=1>8 Children</option>
</select>
</td>
<td align=center><br>
<select id="num_Children4" onchange="return total4()">
<option value=0 selected>0 Children</option>
<option value=1>1 Child</option>
<option value=1>2 Children</option>
<option value=1>3 Children</option>
<option value=1>4 Children</option>
<option value=1>5 Children</option>
<option value=1>6 Children</option>
<option value=1>7 Children</option>
<option value=1>8 Children</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align=center>
<input type=button onclick="amountdue1()" name="total1" value="Find total">
<input type=reset value=Reset>
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="totaldue" size=15 readonly title="Total Amount" maxlength="9" placeholder="$">
</td>
<td align=center>
<input type=button onclick="total2()" value="Find total">
<input type=reset value=Reset>
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="totaldue2" size=15 readonly title="Total Amount" maxlength="9" placeholder="$">
</td>
<td align=center>
<input type=button onclick="total3()" value="Find total">
<input type=reset value=Reset>
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="totaldue3" size=15 readonly title="Total Amount" maxlength="9" placeholder="$">
</td>
<td align=center>
<input type=button onclick="total4()" value="Find total">
<input type=reset value=Reset>
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="totaldue4" size=15 readonly title="Total Amount" maxlength="9" placeholder="$">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: are you sure you added the javascript code just before the `</body>` tag ends?

Comment: is there any other error in your console

Comment: the javascript is between the <body> and </body> and there are no other errors yet

Comment: @Arun P Johny it say:The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Comment: its ok i fixed it, i changed the document.calc to the document. ***name of the form***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function amountdue1() 
{
if (document.calc.familyname1.value === null || document.calc.familyname1.value.length === 0) 
{
alert("Please enter your family name");
}
else
{


var numadults = document.calc.num_Adults1.selectedIndex;
var numchildren = document.calc.num_Children1.selectedIndex;

document.calc.totaldue.value = (numadults * adult) + (numchildren * child) + 10; 

}}
```

You have added extra curly brace inthe function.Also,the function wont end with semi colon.Please check the updated one

Comment: Yes that looks right but it still doesn't print the answer into the textbox

Comment: You are trying to access the using the name attribute where as you haven't defined name for <select> element.Try giving the name for the select tag same as ur id attribute and check one

Comment: I tried changing the function name and it says the same

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the script tag `<script language="JavaScript/text">`, Looks like browser is not parsing your `script` element.

```
<script language="javascript">
```

The language attribute of [script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) does not have any standard values and it is deprecated also you can simply omit it. Or you can use the `type` attribute `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: I looked on a javascript checker and it said there should be alternative